# Hallway Usability Test

Tags: testing, usability

Im required to conduct a **Hallway Usability Test** for developed application and what kind of questions should i ask from the users ? .. is it pre set about regarding the usability goals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being an expert on this...

It depends on what the customer wants. Have a set of quality attributes agreed on before you start the test.

Use this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability

as starting point where I suggest you can make up questions from the paragraph "Useability Considerations".

And have a look at the related questions and answers...

And as a commenter pointed out involve 'passers-by' / people with no experience on the system. I can support that with a recent useability issue we had on a project where the new interaction indeed solved one issue but introduced a major new one which was only discovered during testing with unexperienced users.

Comment: A crucial aspect of Hallway testing is that you use random people as testers, passers by who know nothing of the product.